# Java Datastructures

Tags: java, data-structures

Greetings,

I've been working out of an embedded version of Java where the height of complex structures included in the API was a vector or queue. This usually meant writing structures from scratch when needed.

I am now coming back to the land of the living, I will have full access to a real version of java with all the bells and whistles. This however presents a new problem, the API is quite large.

I was wondering if anyone could tel me about essential data structures which have come to existence in the last 2 years. I'm talking about lists, maps, tree's etc. structures that can handle concurrency and structures.

From what I remember there was a concurrency library however some standard collection structures also had concurrency aspects put in place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start with the Java Collections Trail

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/index.html

This will go over all of the basics.

Then once you're happy take a look at the Concurrent Collections Trail

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/collections.html

However it would also be a good idea to look at the Concurrency package as well.

Answer (score 1):

pre java 1.4 you had Collections with synchronised way of thread control, then from java 1.5 lots of concurrent collections where added. Use of right collection will benefit your application in both performance and and lesser usage of memory.
eg.

Synchronised

1. Vector
2. HashMap
3. HashSet

Concurrent

1. CopyOnwriteArrayList
2. ConcurrentHashMap
3. ConcurrentHashSet
4. ArrayBlockingQueue 
   etc.

You can make any  collection synchronize by saying declaring

```
Collections.synchronizedCollection(c);
```

Again unnecessary use of concurrent/synchronised will give your app performance hit.

links given by pjp gr8
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/index.html
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/collections.html

One you are through with all these collection go through with different opensource collection 
like

guava library by Google http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/

Commons Collections http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/